# My BindingContext event is not triggering when get new value

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm setting up an easy form, and I want to get notified when some inputs of the form were changed, so I binded my model to the form and wrote some handlers for the BindingContextChanged event and each inputs change.

I have already tried to make the inputs two way binding and also by setting the binding context in every input change.

```cs
        private void ContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if(_oldContext == null)
            {
                _oldContext = BindingContext as MyModel;
            }

            var newContext = BindingContext as MyModel;

            if (newContext != _oldContext)
            {
               // Do something...
            }

        }
```

I'm really new to Xamarin.Forms.

I want to know which is the best form to actually do this. Thank you all!
Sorry about my english level, i'm working hard on it.

Comment: do you want an event that triggers when the user updates a control - ie, enters text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to get notified when some inputs of the form were changed, so I binded my model to the form and wrote some handlers for the BindingContextChanged event and each inputs change.

I guess that you bind viewmodel to current page Bindingcontext,for example, there is one entry control in current page, now you want to BindingContext will update when you change Entry'Text?

If yes, I suggest you can implement INotifyPropertyChanged in model, in order to notify when Entry'text changed.

```
 <StackLayout>
        <Entry Text="{Binding str}" />

        <Button
            x:Name="btn1"
            Clicked="Btn1_Clicked"
            Text="btn1" />
    </StackLayout>



   public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{

    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new MyModel();
    }


    private void Btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyModel model = BindingContext as MyModel;
        Console.WriteLine("the string is {0}",model.str);
    }
}

public class MyModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _str;
    public string str
    {
        get { return _str; }
        set
        {
            _str = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("str");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;        
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

You can see some code above,Entry'Text bindind one property str, str in My Model class that implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, so when you change entry'text, BindingContext will update.

Comment: @FedericoStizza, if my reply has resolved your issue, please remember to mark it as answer, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't try it yet. But I think it should work! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Each control will generally have an event for when it is changed. For example, `Entry` has `TextChanged`. So you would subscribe to `TextChanged`. You only need to set the `BindingContext` when the page is initially created. Also, usually if you're using bindings you want to stay away from using events as well unless absolutely necessary. it can create redundant behavior.

Ex. if you have a model that you're using as your `BindingContext` and it has a property `EntryText{get;set;}`, then in Xaml would declare your `Entry` as follows:
`<Entry Text={Binding EntryText}/>`.

[The Model-View-ViewModel Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm)

You should read up on MVVM. You're close to the correct pattern, but not quite there.

Briefly:

View is only UI elements and no logic.

Viewmodel is logic for your view and gets information from/to the view through Bindings. Brings together the View and the Models.

Model is strictly data no logic.

Comment: That's right, I did that. My XAML looks like <Entry Text={Binding EntryText}/>, 
but when text changes it doesn't "notify" to the BindingContext event. I'm not understanding if that would be the behaviour or if I have to suscribe to each input event and handle it by separate. Thank you very much !!

Comment: You handle it through your binding. So as the entry changes your EntryText property will get the new value. The BindingContext generally never changes once it is initially set. Interacting with a control does not change the BindingContext.